# Is there any drawbacks if i want set a default value for the built-in Title column , and why this site column is added inside the "_Hidden" group

Tags: 2013, development, site-collection, administration, site-column

I want to add a defualt value for the built-in site column named Title. now i went to "site collection>>site settings>>site columns" but i can not find the Title column. so i went to "site collection>>site settings>>site content types" from there i can access the Title column from one of the content types which uses this site column, so i set a defualt values for it as follow:-

[image]

but i have noted that the Title is inside a group named "_Hidden",and also it is not listed inside the site columns (as mentioned above), so does this mean or gives an indication that we should not modify the Title site column ? i mean since this column is not available inside the Site Columns and it is placed under the "_Hidden" group so is Microsoft trying to say that we should not modify this site column ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll find any official reference about this, but according to my experience, there's no big (technical) risk in editing the `Title` column (but if you delete it).
You can even change its display name (the internal name `Title` won't move, and that's good news for all pieces of code relying on it!).
You can change its group from `_Hidden` to anything else: `_Hidden` group is a special group whose name (it's hard-coded) simply implies its content is not displayed in the site settings.

**However, note that all changes you do at the site column level will be propagated to *all* lists where the column is in use... for the `Title` column this simply means *all lists* in the site collection!**

Comment: +1 I have done this in the past, and it set the default value of everything in the site collection to be that value, it was a mess. Wouldn't recommend setting it here.

Comment: @EricAlexander Yes i know it will set this defualt value for all the Title fields inside my site collection, and this what i need. since in our case our customer do not want to have the Title field inside the list items , and they only want to add description. this how they sees their requirements.. so what i am planning to do, is to hide this column from my custom content types... and set a defualt value for it,, so when users want to add new items ,, they will not receive any error that the Title column is required.. since the title column will always have the defualt value..

Comment: @Evariste thanks for the reply . can you check my above comment please ,, is my approach valid ?

Comment: I don't fully understand why you need such a complicated solution. If you use custom CT, why don't you go to the CT settings, click on the `Title` column and set it as "Hidden (Will not appear in forms)". That should be enough for your requirements. However note that hiding the `Title` column will prevent you from using the context menu of list items.

Comment: @Evariste i follow this approach as i can not find any other valid approaches to satisfy my needs.. now if i completely hide the title column i will break many built-in features such as the context menu and also search reply on the item titles... so in my case i hide the Title from the custom content type.. and using a workflow i will be setting the Title to have the  following value (itemID + a character). so the Title will have values such as A1, A2 ,A3.. in this case i will keep showing the title inside the list views and using JSLINK i will disable modifying it from the quick edit grid...

Comment: @Evariste so in this case the Title will be hidden from the content types + it will be disabled inside the quick edit grid. so users will not have to worry about entering the item titles (this is the requirement from or customer), and still the search and other built-in features will not get affected since the Title will still be showing .. but if i do not specify a defualt value for the title then users will be receiving an error that the Title is required when they try to add a new item using the quick edit grid,

Comment: since the quick edit grid will still validate the Title even if it is hidden from the content type..